# MySql syntax error; Deleting from two tables in one query possible?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, html, database

Is it not possible to perform two deletes in one query by separating them with a semicolon?

Here is my query:

```
$query="DELETE FROM $sql_table
WHERE EXISTS 
    (
    SELECT 1
    FROM classified
    WHERE classified.poster_password = '$pass'
    AND classified.ad_id = '$id'
    AND classified.classified_id = $sql_table.classified_id
    );
DELETE FROM classified
WHERE classified.poster_password = '$pass'
AND classified.ad_id = '$id'";
```

This gives this error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELETE FROM classified WHERE classified.poster_password = 'xxxxxxx' at line 10

Please help me solve this one, it is starting to give me a headache. I need it in one query...

Thanks

Comment: `mysql_query()` can take only 1 query, if it is what you're using.

Comment: "I need it in one query..." - please elaborate. Can you use something like mysqli_multi_query() ?

Comment: Why do you need it in one query? It makes absolutely no sense as it is not stored in a transaction and therefore the first query will be executed even if the second will fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention which PHP function you use to submit this to MySQL. MySQLi's [multi_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) can handle this.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at transactions

[Using MySQL Transactions](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/MySQL/Using-Transactions-with-MySQL-4.0-and-PHP/)

```
BEGIN

COMMIT
```

Answer (score 1):

you can build tmth like this

```
DELETE t1,t2 FROM t1,t2,t3 WHERE t1.id=t2.id AND t2.id=t3.id
```

Comment: to clarify a bit more, build the SELECT that will show the record you want to DELETE, then switch the "SELECT fields," with "DELETE table", keeping FROM and everything after. Only records in the tables immediately following DELETE with be deleted.

Comment: i was just giving a path to think) with such requests you can do all much easier & better;